# Handle Blank Response From Web Server

Tags: c#, web-services, web, unity-game-engine, http-post

At present, I was facing some sort of weird problem. I turn off my internet connection to put some handling code over their. I thought it will return me some error code but its just giving me blank response rather than showing exception. I got following debug output when I print more details on screen.

[image]

Basically I want to show dialog box when there is no internet connection. But how to handle this situation!!!

Because there is no json response from server side then also there is some bytes I am receiving from server. Here is my code:

```
Dictionary<string,string> headerDisc = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
     headerDisc.Add ("Api-Key", "You API Key");

     WWW www = new WWW (GameConstants.CONTESTANT_LIST_BASE_URL, new byte[] { (byte)0 }, headerDisc);
     yield return www;

     if (www.error == null) {

         Debug.Log ("bytes: " + www.bytes.Length);
         Debug.Log ("size: " + www.size);        
         Debug.Log ("length: " + www.text.Length);
         Debug.Log ("Data: " + www.text);

         if (www.text.Length <= 0) {
             AppManager.Instance.DialogMessage = "No Server Response Found!";
             Camera.main.SendMessage ("ActivateDialogBoxPanel", true, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
         } else {

             JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject (www.text);
             JSONObject messageObj = jsonObj [TAG_MESSAGE];

             string successValueStr = jsonObj [TAG_SUCCESS].ToString ();
             if (successValueStr.Equals (VALUE_TRUE)) 
                 // success
             else 
                 // fail
         }
     } else {
         Debug.Log ("Error: " + www.error);
         AppManager.Instance.DialogMessage = "Error:" + www.error;
         Camera.main.SendMessage ("ActivateDialogBoxPanel", true, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
     }
```

Please give me some suggestion in this. If you want some more information then I am available.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to check if internet connection is disabled show a message to user . for example you can write something like this.

```
  IEnumerator checkInternetConnection(Action<bool> action){
         WWW www = new WWW("http://google.com");
         yield return www;
         if (www.error != null) {
             action (false);
         } else {
             action (true);
         }
     }
```

then in your Start() function write this.

```
void Start(){
     StartCoroutine(checkInternetConnection((isConnected)=>{
         // handle connection status here
     }));
 }
```

Comment: Above source code not work for me because what part of if statement become true that you need to see in my code. www.error is null in my response so definitely your internet connection check code gives me wrong reply too.

Comment: Just invert the if statements, if you need, actually I barely understand what you said.

Comment: If you think about which part of if - else statement execute then you have more clear idea. As per my thinking if my internet was not working then it should give me  www.error != null but at present its doing reverse www.error==null becoming true. So I am confused by this too!!!